# Help with a boolean algebra simplification.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

I know this is annoying and probably easy for some poeple, but this is giving me a hard time, so i thought Id ask here.

~ is NOT; + is OR;

(~A+~B+~C)(~A+B+C)(A+~B+~C)(A+~B+C)(A+B+~C)(A+B+C)

I used a Karnaugh-Veitch Map to get a solution to check if im right later, and got to 
A(~B+~C)(B+C).

How can i solve this using only boolean algebra?

Comment: I'm no expert, but have you tried constructing a table with each statement in it and evaluating the truth values that way?

Comment: I have to use only boolean algebra.. (I mean I know the solution, im just missing the steps inbetween).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Please allow me to use $P'$ instead of $\sim P$)

Use:

**Adjacency**

$PQ + PQ'=P$

$(P+Q)(P+Q')=P$

**Idempotence**

$P+P=P$

$PP=P$

With those:

$$(A'+B'+C')(A'+B+C)(A+B'+C')(A+B'+C)(A+B+C')(A+B+C)$$

$$\overset{\text{Idempotence x 2}}{=}$$

$$(A'+B'+C')(A'+B+C)(A+B'+C')(A+B'+C')(A+B'+C)(A+B+C')(A+B+C)(A+B+C)$$

$$\overset{\text{Commutation}}{=}$$

$$(A+B+C)(A+B+C')(A+B'+C)(A+B'+C')(A+B'+C')(A'+B'+C')(A+B+C)(A'+B+C)$$

$$\overset{\text{Adjacency x 4}}{=}$$

$$(A+B)(A+B')(B'+C')(B+C)$$

$$\overset{\text{Adjacency}}{=}$$

$$A(B'+C')(B+C)$$

Comment: thank you very much!

Comment: @AnotherNoone You're welcome! :)